# How can I constantly watch variables in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Many IDEs have a "variables" pane where you can add/remove variables to watch. These variables value are updated every time you step the code.

Is there such an option in GDB?

Comment: Yes there is such a option: you can type `display <name of variable>` and gdb will print the value of the variable each time it stops. See [section "Automatic Display"](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html) in the documentation. Is this roughly what you wanted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a graphical version of GDB, then you can look at [DDD](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/). It has the exact option you're looking for.

GDB - not being graphical - cannot deliver the kind of functionality in a pane, but you can use the [`display` command](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/display) to show a variable after each step.

I think the most practical way to achieve this (and what I do in practice) is to use `watch`. From the prompt: `watch varname` will break whenever a variable is written to. For global variables, sometimes it's best to get the address of the variable with `print &varname` and then set a watch on the address `watch (int)0xDEADBEEF`, replacing DEADBEEF with the output of the print command, and using something other than int if it isn't an int.

There is also GDB's [TUI mode](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_19.html#SEC200). I don't believe you can tell it to watch a specific variable, but you can have it display the registers (or the source code, or other things) as you step through. In the prompt (after launching `gdb -tui`) enter: `tui reg general`. This will show the variable after each step while it is in a register. [More TUI options](https://beej.us/guide/bggdb/#regasm).

Comment: in general i agree, however gdb has a mode where you can split the screen an watch source,assembly and registers (i believe it called TUI).

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_19.html

So i thought why not variables as well

Comment: `watch (int)0x555555906c60` for example gives me `Cannot watch constant value (int)0x555555906c60'`. When using `watch` with a variable name the watchpoint gets removed when the program leaves the scope where the variable is available. It would be great to have a way to keep watching the memory address independently of the scope.

Comment: @hello_fr1end This is basically what the `-l` argument of [watch](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) does.